# Пагинация + вывод по explode

Tags: html, php

Добрый день.

Есть PHP-скрипт, который выводит информацию из файла постранично. Текстовый файл выглядит так:

```
01.01.2000|Название1|Ссылка1
02.01.2000|Название2|Ссылка2
03.01.2000|Название3|Ссылка3
```

PHP-скрипт пагинации можно [посмотреть тут](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/4iry-a2dk).

Все работает. Но мне нужно, чтобы выводимый на страницу текст оформлялся по шаблону. В PHP-скрипте заменил:

```
print "$file[$i]<br />";
```

На:

```
foreach( $file as $value ):
$value = explode( "|", $value );
{
echo '<div><small>' . $value[0] . '</small> // <span class="blue"><b>' . $value[1] . '</b></span></div>';
echo '<div style="margin:2px 0px 20px 0px"><a href="/news/' . $value[2] . '" class="deep">Подробнее</a></div>';
}

endforeach;
```

Пагинация выводит верное кол-во страниц, функция "explode" разбивает строку по шаблону. Но сам файл выводится весь на одной странице, без пагинации.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: @alegraft, в таком форматировании невозможно разобраться

Comment: Пост переделал. Так понятнее?

Comment: Огромное всем спасибо "за помощь". Вот решение, если кому надо:
Заменяем:
    
    for($i=$first;$i<=$last;$i++):
    if(@$file[$i]):
    print "$file[$i]<br />";
    endif;
    endfor;
    
На:
    
    for($i=$first;$i<=$last;$i++):
    if(@$file[$i]):
    $value=explode("|",trim($file[$i]));
    echo '<div><small>' . $value[0] . '</small> // <span class="blue"><b>' . $value[1] . '</b></span></div>';
    echo '<div style="margin:2px 0px 20px 0px"><a href="/news/' . $value[2] . '/" class="deep">Подробнее</a></div>';
    endif;
    endfor;